# Seat change on Easy Jet

Tags: bookings, fees-and-charges, seating

I have changed my flight with Easy Jet to May 2021. I paid to be seated on my original flight Nov 2020, but have been charged again for the same seats on my new flight. Is this correct?

Comment: What did the T&C of your booking say when you checked them?

Comment: No information in T&C,  and call centre did not know either .

Comment: With most airlines, a paid seat booking is for a specific flight, and if _you_ change the flight, it's lost (it's typically even lost if _they_ change the flight). Little chance for EasyJet to be different.

Comment: Thank you Aganju for the info that is  most helpfull.